# Insecure website error when connecting to AWS Console w/Account Alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication

When I try to access my AWS console using my account name in the URL, I get this error (in Firefox):

---

Your connection is not secure

The owner of mycompanyname.tech.signin.aws.amazon.com has configured their website improperly. To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website.

This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that Firefox may only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not possible to add an exception for this certificate.

---

Why is this happening and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: the problem is that there is a period in the company name/alias (`mycompanyname.tech`). I modified this to remove the period and the error no longer occurred.

Longer answer: I guess the way the wildcard security certificate works is that it only applies to names with 1 subdomain level (before `signin.aws.amazon.com`), and with the period, it broke it up into 2 `['mycompanyname', 'tech']`.

Comment: This is a universal limitation on all wildcard SSL certificates.  See, for example,  https://serverfault.com/a/692224/153161.    Interestingly, though, the dot shouldn't have been possible, because [*"The account alias must be unique across all Amazon Web Services products. It must contain only digits, lowercase letters, and hyphens."*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/console_account-alias.html) ...so it sounds like there could be some missing validation somewhere in the console.